# Automatically set the date today and set another date for expiration

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry I'm beginner in PHP MySQL, I would like to ask something.I'm having a problem how could this be done, In my Database I have table named > 'customer'  and have columns named,

> 'dateStart' , 'dateExpired' 
>   I want my dateStart will automatically set in the input box the date today and set the for expiration for +30 days

**Example**
I have a page of add new customer so i click add new customer then in forms
I will have which automatically inputed the day today and same as expiration which +30 days
 Date Started: October 13, 2015
 Date Expiration: November 12, 2015

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
$dateStart= Date('Y-m-d');
$dateExpired = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateStart. ' + 30 days'));

echo '<input type="text" name= "dateStart" value="'. $dateStart.'"/>';
echo '<input type="text" name= "dateExpired" value="'. $dateExpired .'"/>';
```

Comment: Hi, May I know if this Automatically set/inputted the date today?

Comment: @Edmhar I am glad my answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in MySql 'DATE_ADD' for your case
Here tested example:

```
insert into user_details(dateStart,dateExpired) values($input_date,DATE_ADD($input_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

for more info : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html